# Why the button doesn't get all the attributes from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have created a xml file called `round_button`. It's a simple circular button with a gradient. Here is the simple code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="3000dip" />
            <gradient android:type="linear" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#0DCAAC" />
</shape>
```

And that's the output:
[image]

Here is the code of the xml file of my main activity.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/city"
    android:text="Search"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
   />
```

but the output is this one: [image]

why it doen's have the gradient while the shape is correct?

Comment: Isn't it a button in the color you want?

Comment: yes, I tested it now, it's not the color you want, I shared my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in your code is okay just change **Button** to **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton**  like below and you will be able to achieve your desire result.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/city"
  android:text="Search"
  android:background="@drawable/round_button"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Also a question, can I add listener to the AppCombatbutton with the same way I add listener to a button?

Comment: yes, you can add a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Go to themes.xml and change parent.
parent=Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        //yourcode
    </style>
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: nothing has changed ?

Comment: add ".Bridge" to the end